# explode from two table using UNION and save to different variable

Tags: php, mysql

My tables are adjective and adverb.. both of them has the same structure, "word" and "val". and $apart is a variable for save the result of explode function..

I have some code, here..

```
$apart= explode(" ",$comment);
    if(count($apart)> 0){
        $amount= 0;
        for ($i=0; $i < count($apart); $i++) { 
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM adjective WHERE word= '$apart[$i]' UNION SELECT * FROM adverb WHERE word= '$apart[$i]' ");

        while($s=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
             $amount= $amount + $s['val'];
        }
  }
  $total = $amount;
  $q=mysql_query("INSERT INTO feedback (name, comment, val, date) VALUES ('$name', '$comment', '$total', '$date')");
            if($q==1){
                echo "<script>alert('Success!')</script>";
                echo "<script>window.location='forum.php'</script>";
    }
}
```

my question is.. 
how to separate the result of two explode into different variable?
cause I want to change the formula like :
$amount= $amount + $adjective['val'] * $adverb['val'];

sorry if my explanation was bad... 
I changed the code several times but it ends with error..
anyone can help me please?

Comment: how to separate the result of two explode into different variable? do you want to do this with  $apart?

Comment: no.. i mean in this code..
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM adjective WHERE word= '$apart[$i]' UNION SELECT * FROM adverb WHERE word= '$apart[$i]' ");

I want to select from 2 tables in database and then save it to different variable.. so not just in $querry

Comment: What error it ends with? Can you add DDL for your 2 tables?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the query

```
SELECT * FROM adjective WHERE word = '$apart[$i]' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM adverb WHERE word = '$apart[$i]'
```

with

```
SELECT adv.val * adj.val as factor
FROM adverb adv, adjective adj 
WHERE adv.word = adj.word AND adj.word = '$apart[$i]';
```

if you want to get the sum of all the rows you can use SUM function, but then it would be nice to have all the words in the table APART and you could use this

```
SELECT SUM(adv.val * adj.val) 
FROM adverb adv, adjective adj, apart ap 
WHERE adv.word = adj.word AND adj.word = ap.word;
```

Comment: It would be good if you specify what apart actually is and where it's coming from in your question. Without it it's imposible to answer

Comment: thanks for the advice, its the first time I ask a question.. so my tables are adjective and adverb.. both of them has the same structure, "word" and "val". should I change "if" structure? could u help me?